# How to add file name when importing multiple Excel files to one Access table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, runtime-error, import-from-excel

I am using Access VBA to import multiple Excel files into my Access database. This will be a monthly process with 20-50 files and 10-60K records. I need to include an "Application name" that isn't included within the spreadsheet file itself, but is in its file name. Rather than manually adding the application name to the Excel file I'd like to have it added via my VBA code.

I'm not proficient with Access and have pieced most of this together from searches on how to complete. This "works" but when I run it on larger batches I receive an error "Run-time error '3035': System resource exceeded.' When I remove the section that adds the file name  (loop records) it runs fine. I think it's because the steps aren't ordered efficiently? Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
 Public Function Import_System_Access_Reports()

 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
 Dim fld As DAO.Field
 Dim rstTable As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim lngPos As Long
 Dim strExtension As String
 Dim lngFileType As Long
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strFullFileName As String

 With Application.FileDialog(4) ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
     If .Show Then
         strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
     Else
         MsgBox "No folder specified!", vbCritical
         Exit Function
     End If
 End With
 If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
     strFolder = strFolder & "\"
 End If
 strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")
 Do While strFile <> ""

     lngPos = InStrRev(strFile, ".")
     strTable = "RawData"
     'MsgBox "table is:" & strTable
     strExtension = Mid(strFile, lngPos + 1)
     Select Case strExtension
         Case "xls"
             lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
         Case "xlsx", "xlsm"
             lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml
         Case "xlsb"
             lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12
     End Select
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
         TransferType:=acImport, _
         SpreadsheetType:=lngFileType, _
         TableName:=strTable, _
         FileName:=strFolder & strFile, _
         HasFieldNames:=True ' or False if no headers

'Add and populate the new field
 'set the full file name
 strFullFileName = strFolder & strFile

'Initialize
 Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set tdf = db.TableDefs(strTable)

 'Add the field to the table.
 'tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField("FileName", dbText, 255)

 'Create Recordset
 Set rstTable = db.OpenRecordset(strTable)
 rstTable.MoveFirst

 'Loop records
 Do Until rstTable.EOF
 If (IsNull(rstTable("FileName")) Or rstTable("FileName") = "") Then
     rstTable.Edit
     rstTable("FileName") = strFile
     rstTable.Update
     End If
     rstTable.MoveNext
 Loop

     strFile = Dir

 'Move to the next file
 Loop
     'Clean up
     Set fld = Nothing
     Set tdf = Nothing
     Set db = Nothing
     'rstTable.Close
     Set rstTable = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is simpler and run-time performance should be much better if you eliminate the `Recordset`.  You can execute an `UPDATE` after each `TransferSpreadsheet`

```vb
Dim strFolder As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strFile As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim strExtension As String
Dim lngFileType As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strFullFileName As String
Dim varPieces As Variant

' --------------------------------------------------------
'* I left out the part where the user selects strFolder *'
' --------------------------------------------------------

strTable = "RawData" '<- this could be a constant instead of a variable
Set db = CurrentDb()
' make the UPDATE a parameter query ...
strSQL = "UPDATE [" & strTable & "] SET FileName=[pFileName]" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE FileName Is Null OR FileName='';"
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)

strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    varPieces = Split(strFile, ".")
    strExtension = varPieces(UBound(varPieces))
    Select Case strExtension
    Case "xls"
        lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
    Case "xlsx", "xlsm"
        lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml
    Case "xlsb"
        lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12
    End Select
    strFullFileName = strFolder & strFile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadsheetType:=lngFileType, _
            TableName:=strTable, _
            FileName:=strFullFileName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True ' or False if no headers

    ' supply the parameter value for the UPDATE and execute it ...        
    qdf.Parameters("pFileName").Value = strFile
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

    'Move to the next file
    strFile = Dir
Loop
```