# Access VBA: Adding 'filename' field when importing multiple files

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have some working code that loops through a folder full of Excel files, and imports a table from each into the an Access table.  All I'm trying to do is add a field at the end of the table called *FileName* that has the name of the source Excel file.

I've done some Googling and found this solution:
[How to add file name when importing multiple Excel files to one Access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861815/how-to-add-file-name-when-importing-multiple-excel-files-to-one-access-table)

I've tried to incorporate the solution into my code, but when I reach the execute statement, I get:

> Run-time error '3061' Too few parameters.  Expected 2.

I think the problem is just with the `strSQL` statement and/or the way I'm executing it at the end.

```vb
Public Sub Command0_Click()

Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb()
'make the UPDATE a parameter query ...
strSQL = "UPDATE Test SET FileName=[pFileName] WHERE FileName Is Null OR
FileName='';"
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)

path = "C:\Users\u005984\Desktop\Test\"

'Loop through the folder & build file list
strFile = Dir(path & "*.xlsx")

While strFile <> ""
   'add files to the list
   intFile = intFile + 1
   ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
   strFileList(intFile) = strFile
   strFile = Dir()
Wend

'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'cycle through the list of files
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
    filename = path & strFileList(intFile)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 9, "Test", filename, True

    'Add filename field
    qdf.Parameters("pFileName").Value = strFileList(intFile)
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError   
Next intFile

End Sub
```

I'm new to Access VBA and SQL, and can't figure out why its expecting 2 parameters. Grateful for any help.

Comment: Off the top of my head, try removing the semicolon from the end of the the strSQL query.  Other than that, I'd be curious to know what `qdf.Parameters.Count` is, before the execute.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your SQL query, your's doesn't contain the parameter.

```
strSQL = "PARAMETERS pfilename Text ( 255 ); UPDATE Test SET FileName=[pFileName] WHERE FileName Is Null OR FileName='';"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a *FileName* field is markedly different than updating its value. Hence, you need two SQL action queries: `ALTER` and `UPDATE` statements.

Specifically, the query requires two components that are unknown by the engine: *FileName* column and *[pFileName]* parameter value. Most likely, your Excel worksheets do not have a *FileName* column being imported into *Test* table.

Consider the following setup employing an `ALTER` statement within loop (only on very first iteration since all worksheets append to same table):

```vb
'Add filename field
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)    
    filename = path & strFileList(intFile)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 9, "Test", filename, True

    If intFile = 1 then
       ' ALTER TABLE
       CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [Test] ADD COLUMN [FileName] TEXT(255)", dbFailOnError
    End If

    ' UPDATE TABLE (PASSING PARAM VALUE)
    qdf.Parameters("pFileName").Value = strFileList(intFile)
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError   
Next intFile
```